# Check if data.table query returns empty result set

Tags: r, data.table

I was wondering if there's a dedicated function to check if the result set returned by a data.table query is empty, i.e. zero rows. 
I tried to check which of the available ways is faster and surprisingly the usage of the stock function `nrow()` seems to be faster than using `.N` in data.table. Is this due to the size of the data.table I used in the example or a true in general?

```
dt <- structure(list(Abandon.Period = c(8135L, 1961L, 18307L, 4353L, 2270L, 7905L, 2600L, 2406L, 2286L, 2464L)
                 , Activity.Flag = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L))
                 , .Names = c("Random.Number", "Random.Integer")
                 , row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
microbenchmark(
    a = nrow(dt[Random.Number < 1 ,]) == 0
    ,
    b = dt[Random.Number < 1 ,.N] == 0
    , times = 1000
    )
Unit: microseconds
 expr     min       lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
    a 253.261 281.4845 306.5689 292.8045 309.407 3569.189  1000
    b 311.520 334.7630 354.3346 346.8375 361.931 3342.492  1000
```

Edit:

```
dt <- data.table(Random.Number = rnorm(100000))

microbenchmark(
        a = nrow(dt[Random.Number < 1 ,]) == 0
        ,
        b = dt[Random.Number < 1 ,.N] == 0
        , times = 1000
)
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
    a 1.203515 1.287130 1.795557 1.331504 1.438513 85.51352  1000
    b 1.021796 1.093638 1.607488 1.128352 1.191289 90.10088  1000
```

Comment: If `benchmarks` is based on this small dataset, it is not very useful.  A faster option would be `dt[, sum(Random.Number <1)]`

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the reason, when using more rows the usage of `.N`is faster.

Comment: I also run the microbenchmarks with `c <- dt[, !sum(Random.Number < 1)]` and it is faster

Comment: This was actually just a random filter, so not really, what I intended to use, but thanks for this.

Comment: If you have many other columns, the `nrow` way will be slower since it needs to make the large intermediate table. For a benchmark like this, I think fewer repetitions and a larger size would make more sense. I think `system.time` would make sense if you had a bigger example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
n = 1e7
n_extracol = 20
dt <- data.table(Random.Number = rnorm(n))
dt[, sprintf("%02d", 1:n_extracol) := 22 ]

# test
n = nrow(dt[Random.Number < 1])
all(c(
    dt[Random.Number < 1, .N], 
    dt[, sum(Random.Number < 1)],
    length(dt[Random.Number < 1, which = TRUE]),
    dt[.(v = 1), on = .(Random.Number < v), .N],
    data.table(v = 1)[dt, on = .(v = Random.Number), roll=-Inf, .N, nomatch=0]
) == n) # TRUE

# benchmark
microbenchmark(times = 10,
    nrow = nrow(dt[Random.Number < 1])
    ,
    .N = dt[Random.Number < 1, .N]
    ,
    sum = dt[, sum(Random.Number < 1)]
    ,
    len = length(dt[Random.Number < 1, which = TRUE])
    ,
    join = dt[.(v = 1), on = .(Random.Number < v), .N]
    ,
    roll = data.table(v = 1)[dt, on = .(v = Random.Number), roll=-Inf, .N, nomatch=0]
)
```

Results on my computer:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
 nrow  811.37666  929.83352  963.42572  985.02599 1016.31359 1046.15549    10  b 
   .N   73.84544   74.26404   79.61228   75.33567   75.71378  120.97063    10 a  
  sum   44.11742   44.37590   44.64419   44.54316   44.68093   45.53861    10 a  
  len   69.37396   70.19565   93.39528   70.99561   72.46614  251.16317    10 a  
 join  856.37441  861.35975  898.08747  871.39156  900.91571 1099.40732    10  b 
 roll 1469.73950 1478.51737 1513.49030 1487.32068 1499.74617 1699.44766    10   c
```

It's pretty clear that `nrow` will be worse than `.N`, since it requires making the intermediate table (containing all columns) before counting rows. I don't know why `roll` and `join` are so bad, but I guess they might see further optimization later.

Taking the sum (@akrun's idea) is even faster than `.N`, but isn't my preferred style. Also, the `.N` way may win out after [auto-indexing with inequalities](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1068) is implemented. Anyway, I do tests like the OP's all the time, usually like

```
DT[query, stopifnot(.N == 0L)]
```

If you don't care at all about the number of rows except the comparison against zero, you could use `any` in place of `sum`, but it's only a little faster in this example.

Comment: `length(dt[Random.Number < 1, which = TRUE])` seems to be very fast too

Comment: Thanks, @jangorecki . I've added it now.